# Resultado do JSON em uma table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

Boa tarde,

E coloquei um campo de busca, e assim que a pesquisa for realizada, popular uma tabela com os usuarios encontrados.. A parte da consulta eu consegui fazer, mas agora não estou conseguindo popular(na verdade não tenho nem ideia de como faz, pesquisei mas mesmo assim não consegui) uma tabela com os nomes..

Segue a parte do controller(a responsável por receber o parâmetro, fazer a pesquisa, e retornar os valores)

```
    public JsonResult PorcurarPessoas (string searchString)
    {
        IQueryable<Pessoa> pessoas = db.Pessoa.Where(c => c.deleted_at == null);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            int codigo;
            int.TryParse(searchString, out codigo);

            pessoas = pessoas.Where(s =>
                s.nome.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) ||
                s.id == codigo ||
                s.Juridica.CNPJ.Contains(searchString) ||
                s.Fisica.CPF.Contains(searchString) ||
                s.nome_fantasia.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
            );
        }
        return Json(pessoas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

JS(Peguei essa parte de um exemplo que achei na net..)

```
    $("#procurar").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("PorcurarPessoas", "Movimentacao")',
        data: {
            searchString: $("#searchString").val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            if (!data) {
                alert('Pessoa não encontrada. Por favor verifiquei e tente novamente.');
            } else {
                var tabela = $("#datagrid");
                var rows = "";
                tabela.find("tbody td").remove();
                _.each(data, function (item) {
                    rows += "<tr>";
                    rows += " <td>" + item.nome + "</td>";
                    rows += " <td>" + item.razaosocial + "</td>";
                    rows += " <td>" + item.cpf_cnpj + "</td>";
                    rows += "</tr>";
                });
                tabela.find("tbody").html(rows);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            debugger;
            alert('Error'+data);

        }
    });
```

CSHTML:

```
<table id="datagrid"></table>
```

Eu coloquei um breakpoint na consulta e está funcionando. O problema ta na hr de formar a tabela mesmo.. alguém saberia me dizer como fazer isso?

Comment: Já experimentou debugar o JS no seu navegador favorito? Veja [aqui](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) como fazer.

Answer (score 3):

Se os dados da tua consulta estão a retornar bem, então o problema parece estar na forma com fazes loop dos dados . a função _each julgo ser da tecnologia _underscore. Acho que deves usar $.each:

```
$("#procurar").on("click", function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("PorcurarPessoas", "Movimentacao")',
    data: {
        searchString: $("#searchString").val()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        if (!data) {
            alert('Pessoa não encontrada. Por favor verifiquei e tente novamente.');
        } else {
            var tabela = $("#datagrid");
            var rows = "";
            tabela.find("tbody td").remove();
            $.each(data, function (item) {
                rows += "<tr>";
                rows += " <td>" + item.nome + "</td>";
                rows += " <td>" + item.razaosocial + "</td>";
                rows += " <td>" + item.cpf_cnpj + "</td>";
                rows += "</tr>";
            });
            tabela.find("tbody").html(rows);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        debugger;
        alert('Error'+data);

    }
});
```

Comment: Bom dia, Tentei fazer isso que você sugeriu, mas não adiantou. Quando eu pesquiso ele exibe o erro: "Erro[object Object]", isso somente quando encontra algum resultado, quando não encontra, nem a mensagem de que não foi encontrado cadastro exibe.. E sobre o _each, é da tecnologia _underscore sim, deixei desse jeito pois no exemplo que eu vi estava dessa forma.. Obrigado pela tentativa de ajuda :D..

Comment: Por favor de um exemplo dos dados json que é esperado para poder perceber melhor

Comment: {"nome":"Igor Marcante", "razaosocial":"Igor", "cpf_cnpj": "21574898521"}